# Trying to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}*x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(x+1)^{4}}dx$ by the use of a keyhole contour.

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

I have tried to calculate this integral using a keyhole contour with the positive real axis as a branch cut, but somehow I keep ending up at a result that is not real. The result is supposed to be $\frac{28}{243}\pi\sqrt{3}$

The inner circle integral and outer circle integral vanish while the two line segments differ due to the argument of the logarithm being $2\pi$ for the lower line segment resulting in a difference of $e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}$. So I ended up at the result $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}*x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(x+1)^{4}}dx = 2\pi i*\frac{Res(f(z),-1)}{1-e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}}$  where $Res(f(z),-1) = \frac{28}{162}e^{-\frac{2}{3}\pi i}$

Did I mess up in these calculations somewhere or was my approach wrong?

Edit: my apologies for not including a proper sketch of my contour, but I am new to stackexchange so I unfortunately I did not have the time to figure that out.

Comment: If the calculations are correct, I expect the imaginary parts cancel... Have you tried expanding the terms to check for this?

Comment: It is important to choose the right phase at the singular point. You are integrating counter clockwise along a big circle; therefore, the pole is at $(-1) =e^{\pi i}$

Comment: @abiessu yes I also expected as much but the result seems to be complex in my calculations.

Comment: @Svatoslav indeed, I used the formula for a 4th order pole namely $\frac{1}{3!}\lim_{z\rightarrow -1}\frac{\mathrm{d^3} }{\mathrm{d} z^3}z^2*z^\frac{1}{3}$ to calculate the residue at that point, but perhaps that part was incorrect?

Comment: This is correct. You just have to gather all: 
$$2\pi i \frac{1}{3!}\frac{1}{1-e^{\frac{14}{3}\pi i}}\frac{d^3}{dz^3}z^{\frac{7}{3}}\Big|_{z=e^{\pi i}}=\frac{2\pi i}{6}\frac{7*4*1}{3^3}\frac{e^{-\frac{2}{3}\pi i}}{1-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}}=\frac{28\pi i}{3^4}\frac{e^{-\frac{3}{3}\pi i}}{e^{-\frac{\pi i}{3}}-e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}}=\frac{14\pi}{81\sin(\pi/3)}=\frac{28\pi}{81\sqrt3}$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav I can not believe it, the calculator I used must have not rounded the real part to zero properly, you're a lifesaver, thanks!